# Android App: how to display resultset in Listview?

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc, resultset

I am new to this....
I have a connection to MySQL database and using jdbc connector.
Running queries and displaying to textview no problem,
but how do I display all fetched records in ListView.
I went through tutorials found here and there but they describe how to do it with cursor but I have Resultset as a result of my query.
Please help and Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've run your query you have your ResultSet like in this example:

```
sqlConnection myConn = new sqlConnection();
Statement stmt = myConn.getConnection().createStatement();
ResultSet resSet = stmt.executeQuery(myQuery);
```

You can now read the data step-by-step with a while and fill your LinkedList:

```
List<Example> mExampleList = new LinkedList<Example>();

while (resSet.next()) {
    Example mExample = new Example ();      
    mExample.ID = resSet.getInt("ExampleID");
    mExample.name = resSet.getString("ExampleName");
    [..]
    mExampleList.add(mExample);
}
```

Note: remember to close the connection!

The list "mExampleList" can now become the content of your adapter:

```
CustomAdapterOptimized mAdapter = new CustomAdapterOptimized(mContext, R.layout.example_item, mExampleList);
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

That's it.

---

In this example I supposed you have a class named Example representing the single item; a list named ExampleList containing the items to display; a Context "mContext"; a layout "example_item" representing the view of the single item inside your list.

I am using a CustomAdapterOptimized like this one:

```
private class CustomAdapterOptimized extends ArrayAdapter<Example> {

public CustomAdapterOptimized(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Example> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getViewOptimize(position, convertView, parent);
}

public View getViewOptimize(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
            getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_item, null);
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.exampleID= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.exampleID);
    viewHolder.exampleName= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.exampleName);
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
        Example example = (Example)getItem(position);
        viewHolder.exampleID.setText(example.ID);
        viewHolder.exampleName.setText(example.name);
        return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    public TextView exampleID;
    public TextView exampleName;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Andreaoid. Thank you very much for your response. As I mentioned I am too new to this. Do you mind me asking a few questions: do I have to create a new class example despite that I have a visual listview component? Sorry if I am asking stupid questions. could you please post exapmle class code. tahnks

Comment: The class Example it was just a way to show how it works. It represents the single item of your list:
public class Example {
    public String ID;
    public String name;
}

Comment: Thanks for that. I have tried adopting your solution but I get an error at this line **Example example = (Example)getItem(position);** what is getItem(position) and where should it be declared?

Comment: Error is : **Cannot cast from Entity to ProductItem** ProductItem is my class represaenting single item and has: **public class ProductItem {
  public String art_code; public String art_desc;

 
}**

Comment: Replace Entity with Example, there was a typo in the code. Your original question was about taking data from resultSet, I think the question has been answered... you can go ahead now.